# Is 猫神(ねこがみ) or 猫山(ねこやま) a crazy male japanese name to have?

Tags: names

I'm looking for a unique male japanese name that would sound ok in both english and japanese.
Japanese names sound cool, so I am in search of a male japanese name for myself. Most nice names were taken by many other people, so I'm now considering ねこがみ and ねこやま which don't seem used a lot by people.
Another name derived from ねこ that I just figured out is 猫村(ねこむら).

Is it ok for a man to call himself by one of these names in japan? Would it sound like a mere nickname? How do I better find a cool male japanese name that isn't used much by people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're going to do with this but there are websites like [this](http://myoji-yurai.net/) where you can look up top rare last names as well as [this site](http://topic-good.com/archives/2099.html) shows some first names for men that are more rare.  If you're really looking for a "one-of-a-kind" name you can look into キラキラネーム which are names that are legal (in terms of kanji usage) but put the reading of the characters at their limits.

Whether or not it's 'okay' to call yourself one of these names in Japan is probably up to you.

Comment: I'm going to create a pen name that sounds japanese.

Comment: @crocket In that case you should look into 芸名 (aliases famous people use) some examples are 久石ジョー, 犬山紙子 etc.  Good luck!

Comment: I'll definitely look into 芸名 although I'm not sure if I'll be able to find 芸名 that sounds like a real person name.